# Change UserControl Visibility In MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, progress-bar

I have two `UserControls` in my `MainWindow` as shown.

```
<local:_SplashScreenModal x:Name="_SplashModalControl"  Visibility="Visible"   />

<local:_LoginModal x:Name="_loginModalControl" Visibility="Collapsed"  />
```

One is a splash screen usercontrol, the other is a Login form user control.
My Challenge now is, my Splash Screen has a progress bar, the progress bar also has an event, as shown.

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Name="loading" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,10,0,20" Foreground="White" Width="300" Height="3">
            <ProgressBar.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ProgressBar.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Completed="Storyboard_Completed"  BeginTime="00:00:01">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0.0" To="100.0" Duration="00:00:6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ProgressBar.Value)" >
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <CircleEase />
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ProgressBar.Triggers>
        </ProgressBar>
```

And the event `Completed="Storyboard_Completed"` has to collapse the splash screen and make the login form usercontrol vissible in the `MainWindow`, but i don't know how to go about this, i really need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a reference to the parent window using the `Window.GetWindow` method and then set the `Visibility` property of the other `UserControl` provided that you make it available outside of the window class.

You could do this by setting the `x:FieldModifier` attribute of it to `public` or `internal` in the XAML or expose it through a property of the code-behind.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<local:_LoginModal x:Name="_loginModalControl" Visibility="Collapsed" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

**SplashScreenModal.xaml.cs:**

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    if (parentWindow != null)
    {
        parentWindow._loginModalControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```